# AttributeError: '…' object has no attribute '***_set'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display a list of 'stats' assigned to a 'Profile' which extenders the User model. I have a ForeignKey relating the Stat to the Profile. However, i need it to work so the user doesn't have to be logged in so they share progress to users who are not a member of the site.

I'm trying to use _set for a backwards relationship on the ForeignKey. I think where it's tripping up is because the 'Stat' model and the 'Profile' models are inside different apps. Would this be causing the issue? Code below:

```
class Stat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=False)
    image = CloudinaryField('image', default="thumbnail_mqe6ne", blank=True)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

// Profile view

```
def profile_item(request, id):
    p = Profile.objects.get(id=7)
    user_stats = p.stat_set.all()

    context = {
        "p": p,
        "user_stats": user_stats,

    }
    return render(request,"profile/profile_share.html", context)
```

The view i'm receiving:

```
'Profile' object has no attribute 'stat_set'
```

As far as i'm aware using the backwards reference you need to specify the model you are targeting in lowercase. Full stack trace below:

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/profile/7/

```
Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 2.7.14
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'stats',
 'home',
 'blog',
 'challenge',
 'haystack',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'ckeditor',
 'django_cron',
 'anymail',
 'templated_email',
 'django_social_share',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'storages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'cloudinary_storage',
 'cloudinary',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_cleanup',
 'django_instagram',
 'embed_video',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'filer',
 'reversion',
 'bootstrap3',
 'rest_framework',
 'meta',
 'import_export',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'solid_i18n.middleware.SolidLocaleMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/vagrant/bodymakeover/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/vagrant/bodymakeover/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/vagrant/bodymakeover/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/vagrant/bodymakeover/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/vagrant/bodymakeover/home/views.py" in profile_item
  117.     user_stats = p.stat_set.all()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile/7/
Exception Value: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'stat_set'
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Profile` and `Stat` aren't related to one another - they're both related to `User`. You should perform this reverse lookup from the `User` model, or create a ForeignKey relation from `Stat` to `Profile`.

Comment: Thank you!! Makes perfect sense. I was overlooking the issue.

Answer (score 2):

@souldeux has right. And if you want search stats for Profile you should build Queryset like

```
p = Profile.objects.get(id=7)
user_stats = p.user.stat_set.all()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!